# How to setup angular 2 in Eclipse for Mac OS X?

Tags: eclipse, macos, angular, eclipse-plugin, angular-cli

I have installed both node.js and angular 2 plugin in Eclipse neon.
But on creation of a new project I am getting the followiong error :

> /bin/bash: line 1: ng: command not found

So can any one either explain the full setup for angular 2 or solution to the above error ?

Comment: did you install angular-cli to your global invironment?

Comment: No. But something @angular-cli is already there in .npm folder.
So do I need to install angular-cli again?

Comment: try 'npm install -g @angular/cli' to install it once again.

Comment: You can install 1.2.0-SNAPSHOT and specify directory which host "ng" with "Windows/Preferences" -> "JavaScript / TypeScript / Angular2 / CLI" "ng custom file". But I'm working on this issue tps://github.com/angelozerr/angular2-eclipse/issues/52 to show the used @angular/cli used fot the wizard. Please note now you must use @angular/cli and not angular-cli

Comment: @Pengyy 
After angular/cli installationagain its giving following error :
[
 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/config/config.js:16
    constructor(_configPath, schema, configJson, fallbacks = []) {
SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:387:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
    at Object.<anonymous>
]

Comment: Above error resolved... yet it's saying  ng : command not found
The specified command init is invalid. For available options, see `ng help`.

Comment: 1.2.0-SNAPSHOT doesn't use "ng init" now (which is included in the last version of angular cli) but "ng new" for eclipse wizard CLI project